# TypeORM AND Find Option

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have products with a price, I want to find products whose price will be less than 10 but more than 5. So that SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE products.price < 10 AND products.price > 5
```

Is it possible to do this without using Query Builder?

I don't find the And operator in the documentation

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way is to use Between Operator in your case. Between(1, 10) 1<x<10

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use **where** operator.

```
userRepository.find({ where: { firstName: "Timber", lastName: "Saw" } });
```

This code executes this query:

```
SELECT * FROM "user" WHERE "firstName" = 'Timber' AND "lastName" = 'Saw'
```

And if you want to use **OR**, you use an array of conditions:

```
userRepository.find({
    where: [
        { firstName: "Timber", lastName: "Saw" },
        { firstName: "Stan", lastName: "Lee" },
    ],
});
```

This code will executes this query:

```
SELECT * FROM "user" WHERE ("firstName" = 'Timber' AND "lastName" = 'Saw') OR ("firstName" = 'Stan' AND "lastName" = 'Lee')
```

More infos in the doc: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/find-options.md

Comment: This only works if your search parameters are different, but I need to set two conditions for the price, this will cause an error, since you cannot pass
{ price: 'somethig', price: 'something" }

Comment: Then what you want is "Between" operator. Look at the link in my post, all the operators like "Between", "lessThan" or "moreThan" are explained.

Answer (score 0):

These docs clarify how to use find like SQL
https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/find-options

Note that for conditional where and other statements, you need QueryBuilder.